# How to stream a video file from an s3 presigned url using videojs

Tags: jquery, node.js, amazon-s3, video.js, pre-signed-url

I am currently trying to stream a small video file from an s3 bucket. The size of my video file on s3 bucket is 23.5 Mb and its format is video/quicktime. I am using the following code in jQuery to retrieve the presigned URL

```
 const video = await fetch('http://localhost/getUrl', {
    method: "POST",
    body: "key",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
const result = await video.text();
```

The result variable returns a presigned url which when clicked downloads the video file.

My html code is the following

```
<video id="vid1" class="video-js " controls preload="auto" width="640" height="265">
</video>
```

After That I am setting my src in id vid1 as the following

```
if (result){
    videojs("vid1").src([
        { type: 'video/quicktime', src: result }
      ]);
}
```

However the file is not playing back and I recieve the following error

```
video.min.js:1 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. st {code: 4, message: "The media could not be loaded, either because the …rk failed or because the format is not supported."}.
```

How would I use videojs with presigned urls to stream a video file from an s3 bucket

Comment: How does the presigned url look like? Are you able to open it in a new tab?

Comment: When I put in new tab or click it. it downloads the file

Comment: Ok, it seems S3 side works great. Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: yeah I tried chrome, safari and firefox

Comment: I think I knew the error the downloaded file is a base64 encoded string. Is there a way to upload the video as binary instead of base64 encoded string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't play because the browser can't play `video/quicktime`. mov is not a format for HTML5 video. Try using an mp4 with h264/acc and the `video/mp4` type.

Comment: true that what happened. do you know any npm package that convert videos to Mp4

Comment: ffmpeg can do it but on backend only